# How can I get credit card image from customers card number?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment, credit-card

I am working on a feature for a React Native app (and React web app) that allows users to save their payment methods in their virtual wallet within the app. When the user enters their card information, I want to get the actual image of the card to display in their wallet. PayPal, Amazon and Apple Pay all have this functionality, my question is how and where are they getting these card images? It looks like both Amazon and PayPal are hosting their images internally but my question is where are they getting these images to begin with? and how are they associating the card number to the correct image?

**Example of PayPal blank Wells Farg card image:**

https://pics.paypal.com//00/s/OTY5WDE1MzZYUE5H/p/NWFiYWQyMTQtNTY1ZC00NGZmLWJiYTItNGE2ZmQ2MDI3NmEw/image__140.png

**PayPal Example:**

[Card displayed in PayPal wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASMw9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the above scenario use can use the below card image link and download the card sample images and as per type of the card ( like for eg visa, rupay, martercard, etc ) you can use different image background (  tag)  and display you data over it in react native.

Card image link : https://www.freevector.com/bank-cards-templates# (you can get more from google as well)

I have also create a demo : https://snack.expo.dev/7hwToa0zd

Image Link : https://im.ge/i/FEsMKa

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements of the ask, I need to get the actual card image from the actual bank like Wells Fargo

Answer (score 0):

> how and where are they getting these card images?

These providers have built their own database of images, which is easy for the likes of PayPal to do because they work with just about every bank + network (Visa etc.) Perhaps you can scrape some of the images from PayPal, as they all seem to start with `https://pics.paypal.com//00/s/OTY5WDE1MzZYUE5H/p/`.

> how are they associating the card number to the correct image

Now this is the easier part. The first four to eight numbers of most payment networks' cards are uniquely linked to one institution. This number is known as the [Bank Identification Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_(IIN)). These numbers are designated by the ISO as part of [ISO 7812](https://www.iso.org/standard/70484.html) (technically they appoint a company in each country to take applications to get a BIN, in the USA it's the [American Banker's Association](https://www.aba.com/about-us/our-story/issuer-identification-numbers), and sometimes companies rent out their BIN numbers but none of this detail is really important).

You can use a service like [IIN List](https://iinlist.com/), and both [Visa](https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/visa-bin-attribute-sharing-service/docs-getting-started) and [Mastercard](https://developer.mastercard.com/bin-lookup/documentation/) provide APIs for their own cards. Some of these data sources (especially free ones) can be outdated so be wary.

So, to associate a given card number with a financial institution, determine the BIN. The limitation here is still that you don't know what specific product the card is for (like "Platinum Debit Card" in your reference image), only banks do and again this is where companies like PayPal have the upper hand.